# not able to find differences mysql with two db / tables

Tags: mysql

i have two databases on same server with different db and tables neither are complete - rets is missing lat/lngs and open is missing addresses from rets.
i need to find missing info and fix. so i tried to see if i can find differences first as i didnt know how to do any of this but that is not even working after many hours of googling this.

```
USE garry_realestatedb_info;
SELECT CONCAT( HSN,  ' ', CP,  ' ', STR,  ' ', STREETSUFFIX,  ', ', CIT,  '    ', STATE,  ' ', ZP ) AS addy1
FROM  `rets_property_residentialproperty`
minus
USE complete_localmap2;
select CONCAT(addrStreetNum,' ',addrStreet,', ',addrCity,' ',addrRegion,' ',addrPostcode) as addy2 
FROM `Open_Address`;
```

ive tried

```
SELECT CONCAT(garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.HSN,  ' ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.CP,  ' ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.STR,  ' ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.STREETSUFFIX,  ', ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.CIT,  ' ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.STATE,  ' ', garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty.ZP ) AS addy1
FROM  `garry_realestatedb_info.rets_property_residentialproperty`;
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select CONCAT(addrStreetNum,' ',addrStreet,', ',addrCity,' ',addrRegion,' ',addrPostcode) as addy2 
FROM `complete_localmap2\.Open_Address`);
```

in attempt to get db error fixed(yes i know second didnt have db)
i seam to be spinning my wheels here and not getting anyplace as thisis not even what i want for end result so i figured is ask for help as just showing results of a test doe snot fix my problem with the two databases

what im really trying to do is

(thought id try and find differences first as im not sure how all this works but if there is a faster way to achieve my goal im all game)

check both address and lat/lng in both tables

1: check if address is in rets and not open (save lat/lng & address to open if present)

2: check if lat/lng is in open and not rets (save lat/lng to rets if present)

3: check if lat/lng is in rets and not open (save lat/lng to open if present)

---

my tables info
Database: garry_realestatedb_info »Table: rets_property_residentialproperty"New no dupes"
rets_property_residentialproperty

HSN

CP

STR

STREETSUFFIX

CIT

STATE

ZP

LAT

LNG

Database: complete_localmap2 »Table: Open_Address

Open_Address

addrStreetNum

addrStreet

addrCity

addrRegion

addrPostcode

addrLat

addrLng

any help you may provide thank you in advance im really stuck here and its a bit over my head in a  complex mysql (i can look up things just fine this is a bit more involved)

---

changed code to coincide with comments

```
    SELECT CONCAT(`garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`HSN`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CP`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STR`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STREETSUFFIX`,  ', ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CIT`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STATE`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`ZP` ) AS addy1
    FROM  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`
    minus
    select CONCAT(`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreetNum`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreet`,', ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrCity`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrRegion`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrPostcode`) as addy2 
    FROM `complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`;
```

getting error of

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select CONCAT(`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreetNum`,' ',`complete_' at line 4
```

this works fine

```
  SELECT CONCAT(  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`HSN` ,  ' ',  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CP` ,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STR` ,  ' ',  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STREETSUFFIX` ,  ', ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CIT` ,  ' ',  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STATE` ,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`ZP` ) AS addy1
  FROM  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty` 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

so does this

```
    select CONCAT(`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreetNum`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreet`,', ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrCity`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrRegion`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrPostcode`) as addy2 
    FROM `complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`;
```

so how do i find the differences please

Comment: Try `\`garry_realestatedb_info\`.\`rets_property_residentialproperty\`` and `\`complete_localmap2\`.\`Open_Address\``

Comment: this should be the correct answer but its a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **NOT** switch a database in the middle of a query like that.

You **CAN** use absolute addressing:

```
SELECT schema.table.field
FROM schema.table

minus

SELECT otherschema.othertable.field
FROM otherscheme.othertable
```

Comment: SELECT CONCAT( HSN,  ' ', CP,  ' ', STR,  ' ', STREETSUFFIX,  ', ', CIT,  ' ', STATE,  ' ', ZP ) AS addy1
FROM `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`;
minus
select CONCAT(addrStreetNum,' ',addrStreet,', ',addrCity,' ',addrRegion,' ',addrPostcode) as addy2 
FROM `complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`;

Comment: dam comment system does not allow lines..grrr -  so do i have to do each field too..wow if i do.

Comment: you only need as many identifiers as are necessary to UNIQUELY identify your fields/tables. e.g. if both dbs have a table "foo" with a field "bar", then you need `select db1.foo.bar, db2.foo.bar`. but if the tables are "argle" and "bargle", then a simple `select argle.id, bargle.id from argle join db2.bargle` etc...

Comment: till i figure out stupid comment system in too long in reply of whats going on i so hate this right now..ugggg cant show what im doing

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(`garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`HSN`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CP`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STR`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STREETSUFFIX`,  ', ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`CIT`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`STATE`,  ' ', `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`.`ZP` ) AS addy1

Comment: FROM  `garry_realestatedb_info`.`rets_property_residentialproperty`
minus

Comment: select CONCAT(`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreetNum`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreet`,', ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrCity`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrRegion`,' ',`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrPostcode`) as addy2 
FROM `complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`;

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select CONCAT(`complete_localmap2`.`Open_Address`.`addrStreetNum`,' ',`complete_' at line 4

Comment: not sure what im doing wrong i checked all the ` im malformed for some reason - is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't post code into comments. You can edit your question. The above crap (and it is crap while in a comment) is COMPLETELY unreadable.

Comment: this answer is also correct in its formatting but  Charlotte Dunois did not make it an answer - ill wait a bit and see if she does if not ill accept the one from Marc B.